Expo application does very slow requests when published in stores
I have an expo app that works really fine on the emulator. But when I publish it in the stores (appstore and playstore), SOMETIMES the requests (GET, POST, PUT) are very slow.
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.7",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@rneui/base": "^0.0.0-edge.2",
    "@rneui/themed": "^0.0.0-edge.2",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.48.0",
    "@types/react-native-background-timer": "^2.0.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.13",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.19",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "punycode": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.10",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-mmkv": "^2.12.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-virtualized-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },

This is what I'm using for the app.
I tried to switch from expo async storage to MMKV but I didn't notice any better results
